# The smallest abundant numbers $n$ with abundancy (index) $I(n)\geq 7$

Tags: number-theory

Let $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum of positive divisors of the integer $n$. For every integer $n$, we define $I(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$. Is there any reference or a simple algorithm that I can find the list of smallest numbers such that $I(n)\geq 7$. I know some methods for finding these numbers. but I think my methods are not optimal enough.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the table from http://oeis.org/A004394 I get the smallest $n$ with $\sigma(n) \ge 7n$ is $n=1970992304700453905270400$ with $\sigma(n)/n \approx 7.016$.  This is $a_{149}$ in that table.

Entry $a_{2000}$ in the table has $\sigma(a_{2000})/a_{2000} \approx 11.64$, so we could find the least $n$ with $\sigma(n)/n \ge 8$ and $9$ and $10$ and $11$ by looking there.

Comment: Dear friend, I am really thankful for your answer. But I knew that. In fact, I want to find at least the 10 first abundant numbers such that $I(n)>7$ or I want to find the smallest abundant number such that $I(n)>7$ and $7|\sigma(n)$.